# function that prints true 75% of the time

Tags: algorithm

This question isn't for any specific interview or assignment, just a question that showed up on Quora but no one answered. 
How would you implement a function (any language really) that returns true 75% of the time. Statistics is not my strong point and for me the way I would do it but I have a inkling is wrong is

```
void retTrue(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    if( (rand() % 4) == 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Why is that wrong? Assuming `rand()` returns a random integer on a uniform distribution, that seems fine.

Comment: could shorten to `return (rand()%4 != 0)` and the return type should probably be bool, otherwise I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: I think you mean `return (rand()%4 != 0)` ?

Comment: @Jason thanks fixed with ninja edit

Comment: Wouldn't you want to switch your return true and return false if your looking for it to return `true` 75% of the time?

Comment: You also want to seed the RNG once, not each and every time. Move `srand(time(NULL));` somewhere else (`main`, for example).

Comment: If you want to be completely sure, you can build an array of 100 elements (true / false with 75 true), shuffle it and increase the index each time to return a different value with the function. When you reach the end of the array, you shuffle it again.

Comment: Quora. Yeah. Terrible, terrible place.

Comment: Depends on the definition - arguably, you could skip the call to rand() altogether, and use modulo on the time, or even use a static and round robin it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have will return `true` 25% of the time.

How about this?

```
bool retTrue()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    if ( (rand() % 4) == 0 ) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

But this also returns `true` 75% of the time -- every fourth time, like clockwork:

```
static int counter = 1;  // global or out-of-scope variable

bool retTrue_anotherOne()
{
    bool returnValue;
    if ((counter % 4) == 0)
        counter = 0;
        returnValue = false;
    else
        returnValue = true;

    counter++;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Or this also returns `true` 75% of the time -- 75 `true`s in a row, then 25 `false`s:

```
static int counter = 0;  // global or out-of-scope variable

bool retTrue_anotherOne()
{
    bool returnValue;
    if (counter < 75)
        returnValue = true;
    else
        returnValue = false;

    counter = (counter + 1) % 100;
    return returnValue;
}
```

It all depends on what kind of distribution of "75% of the time" you want!

Comment: Thank! what i wrote was just very quickly unformatted C. For some reason I thought mine wasn't really following any proper distributions.

Comment: And of course it could be `return (rand() % 4) != 0;`.  (We are of course assuming here that `rand` is well distributed, which it generally is not, I understand.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one potential problem with your function.  `rand()` will return a random integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, and although there are no real guarantees, RNGs are designed to generate a uniform distribution over this interval.  However, when you use the modulo operator, as in

```
(rand() % 4) == 0
```

you are only looking at the bottom two bits of the random number.  The problem is, in some random number generators, the randomness of lower order bits can be very weak.  A safer way to get a series independent random events that occur 25% of the time is

```
((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) < 0.25
```

The randomness of `rand()` as an element over the whole interval `[0,RAND_MAX]` is more reliable than the randomness of individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the suggestions from the comments:

Seed your RNG somewhere:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Then the function is simple:

```
bool retTrue(){
    return (rand()%4 != 0);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to make it `!=`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call srand inside the function. time() has a 1 second resolution. If I called that function 100 times in less than one second I would get the same results every time.

Second rand usually isn't a very good random number generator, you are unlikely to get a perfect 75% ratio out of it.

Third your return type is void that isn't going to return anything except a compiler error.

How about:

```
bool retTrue(){
static unsigned int n = 0;
n++;
return n % 4 != 0;
}
```

There was no mention of it needing to be random.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate numbers using `Random Number Generator` in java. I think this should print `True` 75% of time given `rand()`generates numbers with equal probability. Correct me if this is wrong

**Pseudo-Code**

```
 int generateNumber()
  {
     Random r = new Random();
     int seed = r.nextInt(100);
     if(seed < 25){
     return false;
     }else
     {
     return true;
     }        
  }
```